# Work manager getworkinfobyliveiddata on changed function not being called

Tags: java, android

This is the implementation of downloadRequestqueue class inside a library .This java file uses work manager inside its add request function.But the work manager getworkinfobyliveId function is not called.I think the problem is because of lifecycle owner of this java class which also I have implemented in this class

```
public class DownloadRequestQueue extends AppCompatActivity  implements LifecycleOwner  
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mLifecycleRegistry=new LifecycleRegistry(this);
        mLifecycleRegistry.markState(Lifecycle.State.CREATED);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mLifecycleRegistry=new LifecycleRegistry(this);
        mLifecycleRegistry.markState(Lifecycle.State.STARTED);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Lifecycle getLifecycle() {
        mLifecycleRegistry=new LifecycleRegistry(this);
        Log.d("uu",mLifecycleRegistry+"");
        return mLifecycleRegistry;
    }

    public   DownloadRequestQueue(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

        currentRequestMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        sequenceGenerator = new AtomicInteger();

    }

    public static void initialize(Context context) {
        getInstance(context);


    }

    public static DownloadRequestQueue getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (DownloadRequestQueue.class) {
                if (instance == null) {

                    instance = new DownloadRequestQueue(context);
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private int getSequenceNumber() {
        return sequenceGenerator.incrementAndGet();
    }

    public void pause(int downloadId) {
        DownloadRequest request = currentRequestMap.get(downloadId);
        if (request != null) {
            request.setStatus(Status.PAUSED);
        }
    }

    public void resume(int downloadId) {
        final Response response = new Response();
        final DownloadRequest request = currentRequestMap.get(downloadId);
        if (request != null) {

            request.setStatus(Status.QUEUED);
            request.deliverStartEvent();
            SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Log.d("fff",request.getOnProgressListener()+"");
            String json = gson.toJson(request);
            prefsEditor.putString("SerializableObject", json);
            prefsEditor.commit();
            Data data = new Data.Builder().putInt("ID", downloadId).build();
            final OneTimeWorkRequest workRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class).setInputData(data).build();
            WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(workRequest);
            WorkManager.getInstance().getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(workRequest.getId()).observe(this, new Observer<WorkInfo>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(@Nullable WorkInfo workInfo) {
                    if (workInfo != null) {
                        Log.d("this","dip");
                        if (workInfo.getState().isFinished()) {
                            Data data = workInfo.getOutputData();
                            String output = data.getString("Response");
                            if (output.equals(Status.CANCELLED + "")) {
                                response.setCancelled(true);
                            }
                            if (output.equals(Status.PAUSED + "")) {
                                response.setPaused(true);
                            }
                            if (output.equals("abc")) {
                                Error error = new Error();
                                error.setConnectionError(true);
                                error.setConnectionException(new Exception());
                                response.setError(error);
                            }
                            if (output.equals("def")) {
                                Error error = new Error();
                                error.setServerError(true);
                                response.setError(error);
                            }
                        }
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            request.deliverSuccess();
                        } else if (response.isPaused()) {
                            request.deliverPauseEvent();
                        } else if (response.getError() != null) {
                            request.deliverError(response.getError());
                        } else if (!response.isCancelled()) {
                            request.deliverError(new Error());
                        }

                    }
                }
            });

//            request.setFuture(Core.getInstance()
//                    .getExecutorSupplier()
//                    .forDownloadTasks()
//                    .submit(new DownloadRunnable(request)));
        }
    }

    private void cancelAndRemoveFromMap(DownloadRequest request) {
        if (request != null) {
            request.cancel();
            currentRequestMap.remove(request.getDownloadId());
        }
    }

    public void cancel(int downloadId) {
        DownloadRequest request = currentRequestMap.get(downloadId);
        cancelAndRemoveFromMap(request);
    }

    public void cancel(Object tag) {
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, DownloadRequest> currentRequestMapEntry : currentRequestMap.entrySet()) {
            DownloadRequest request = currentRequestMapEntry.getValue();
            if (request.getTag() instanceof String && tag instanceof String) {
                final String tempRequestTag = (String) request.getTag();
                final String tempTag = (String) tag;
                if (tempRequestTag.equals(tempTag)) {
                    cancelAndRemoveFromMap(request);
                }
            } else if (request.getTag().equals(tag)) {
                cancelAndRemoveFromMap(request);
            }
        }
    }

    public void cancelAll() {
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, DownloadRequest> currentRequestMapEntry : currentRequestMap.entrySet()) {
            DownloadRequest request = currentRequestMapEntry.getValue();
            cancelAndRemoveFromMap(request);
        }
    }

    public Status getStatus(int downloadId) {
        DownloadRequest request = currentRequestMap.get(downloadId);
        if (request != null) {
            return request.getStatus();
        }
        return Status.UNKNOWN;
    }

    public void addRequest(final DownloadRequest request) {
        Log.d("did", request.getUrl() + "");
        final Response response = new Response();
        Log.d("yoii", request.getOnProgressListener()+"");
        request.setStatus(Status.QUEUED);
        abc=request.getOnProgressListener()+"";
        onProgressListener1=request.getOnProgressListener();
             currentRequestMap.put(request.getDownloadId(), request);
        SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Log.d("fff",request.getOnProgressListener()+"");
        request.setOnProgressListener(request.getOnProgressListener());
        String json = gson.toJson(request);
        ArrayList<Integer> arrayList=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        arrayList.add(1);

        prefsEditor.putString("SerializableObject", json);
        prefsEditor.commit();

        if (request != null) {
            Log.d("999", currentRequestMap.get(request.getDownloadId()).getUrl() + "");
        }
        if (request == null) {
            Log.d("none", "bro");
        }

        if (request != null) {
            Log.d("all", request.getUrl() + "");
        }
        if (request == null) {
            Log.d("none", "bro");
        }

        Data data = new Data.Builder().putInt("ID", request.getDownloadId()).putString("status", request.getStatus() + "").build();
        OneTimeWorkRequest workRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class).setInputData(data).build();
        WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(workRequest);
        Log.d("boss", "pls");
        WorkManager.getInstance().getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(workRequest.getId()).observe(this, new Observer<WorkInfo>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable WorkInfo workInfo) {
                Log.d("abd","see");
                if(workInfo==null){
                    Log.d("bug","buggy");
                }
                if (workInfo != null) {
                    Log.d("boss2", "pls2");
                    if (workInfo.getState().isFinished()) {
                        Log.d("boss3", "pls3");
                        Data data = workInfo.getOutputData();
                        String output = data.getString("Response");
                        Log.d("boss4", output);
                        if (output.equals(Status.CANCELLED + "")) {
                            response.setCancelled(true);
                        }
                        if (output.equals(Status.PAUSED + "")) {
                            response.setPaused(true);
                        }
                        if (output.equals("succ")) {
                            response.setSuccessful(true);
                        }
                        if (output.equals("abc")) {
                            Error error = new Error();
                            error.setConnectionError(true);
                            error.setConnectionException(new Exception());
                            response.setError(error);
                        }
                        if (output.equals("def")) {
                            Error error = new Error();
                            error.setServerError(true);
                            response.setError(error);
                        }
                    }
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        request.deliverSuccess();
                    } else if (response.isPaused()) {
                        request.deliverPauseEvent();
                    } else if (response.getError() != null) {
                        request.deliverError(response.getError());
                    } else if (!response.isCancelled()) {
                        request.deliverError(new Error());
                    }

                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void finish(DownloadRequest request) {
        currentRequestMap.remove(request.getDownloadId());
    }



}






    public MyWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
         currentRequestMap=new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
         mPrefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        int a = getInputData().getInt("ID",2);
        String statu = getInputData().getString("status");
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = mPrefs.getString("SerializableObject", "");
        if(json.equals("")){
            Log.d("noii","nn");
        }
        request = gson.fromJson( json, DownloadRequest.class);
        Log.d("zoiiii",currentRequestMap.get(a)+"")
        if(request!=null){
            Log.d("soii",request.getStatus()+"");
        }
        else{
            Log.d("loii","toy");
        }
        Response response = new Response();
        if (request.getStatus() == Status.CANCELLED) {
            response.setCancelled(true);
            Data output = new Data.Builder()
                    .putString("Response",response+"")
                    .build();
            return Result.failure(output);
        } else if (request.getStatus() == Status.PAUSED) {
            response.setPaused(true);
            Data output = new Data.Builder()
                    .putString("Response",response+"")
                    .build();
            return Result.failure(output);
        }

        try {
            Log.d("koko","gogo");
            if(request.getOnProgressListener()==null){
                Log.d("dope",request.getUrl()+"");


                //progressHandler = new ProgressHandler(request.getOnProgressListener());
            }
            if (request.getOnProgressListener() != null) {
                Log.d("toll","lol");
                progressHandler = new ProgressHandler(request.getOnProgressListener());
            }

            Log.d("suppp","ppp");
            tempPath = Utils.getTempPath(request.getDirPath(), request.getFileName());

            File file = new File(tempPath);

            DownloadModel model = getDownloadModelIfAlreadyPresentInDatabase();
            Log.d("dupp","nupp");
            if (model != null) {
                Log.d("love","no");
                if (file.exists()) {
                    request.setTotalBytes(model.getTotalBytes());
                    request.setDownloadedBytes(model.getDownloadedBytes());
                } else {
                    removeNoMoreNeededModelFromDatabase();
                    request.setDownloadedBytes(0);
                    request.setTotalBytes(0);
                    model = null;
                }
            }
            Log.d("ab","devel");
            httpClient = ComponentHolder.getInstance().getHttpClient();
            Log.d("ggs","iipu");
            httpClient.connect(request);

            if (request.getStatus() == Status.CANCELLED) {
                response.setCancelled(true);
                Data output = new Data.Builder()
                        .putString("Response",response+"")
                        .build();
                return Result.failure(output);
            } else if (request.getStatus() == Status.PAUSED) {
                response.setPaused(true);
                Data output = new Data.Builder()
                        .putString("Response",response+"")
                        .build();
                return Result.failure(output);
            }

            httpClient = Utils.getRedirectedConnectionIfAny(httpClient, request);

            responseCode = httpClient.getResponseCode();

            eTag = httpClient.getResponseHeader(Constants.ETAG);
            Log.d("sipi","kipi");
            if (checkIfFreshStartRequiredAndStart(model)) {
                model = null;
                Log.d("lova","nova");
            }

            if (!isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d("lvv","nppp");
                Error error = new Error();
                error.setServerError(true);
                error.setServerErrorMessage(convertStreamToString(httpClient.getErrorStream()));
                error.setHeaderFields(httpClient.getHeaderFields());
                error.setResponseCode(responseCode);
                response.setError(error);
                Data output = new Data.Builder()
                        .putString("Response","abc")
                        .build();
                return Result.failure(output);
            }

            setResumeSupportedOrNot();
            Log.d("coder","npppp");
            totalBytes = request.getTotalBytes();

            if (!isResumeSupported) {
                deleteTempFile();
            }

            if (totalBytes == 0) {
                totalBytes = httpClient.getContentLength();
                request.setTotalBytes(totalBytes);
            }

            if (isResumeSupported && model == null) {
                createAndInsertNewModel();
            }

            if (request.getStatus() == Status.CANCELLED) {
                response.setCancelled(true);
                Data output = new Data.Builder()
                        .putString("Response",response+"")
                        .build();
                return Result.failure(output);
            } else if (request.getStatus() == Status.PAUSED) {
                response.setPaused(true);
                Data output = new Data.Builder()
                        .putString("Response",response+"")
                        .build();
                return Result.failure(output);
            }

            Log.d("dodo","soso");

            request.deliverStartEvent();
            Log.d("coco","momo");
            inputStream = httpClient.getInputStream();

            byte[] buff = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

            if (!file.exists()) {
                if (file.getParentFile() != null && !file.getParentFile().exists()) {
                    if (file.getParentFile().mkdirs()) {
                        //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
                        file.createNewFile();
                    }
                } else {
                    //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
                    file.createNewFile();
                }
            }

            this.outputStream = FileDownloadRandomAccessFile.create(file);

            if (isResumeSupported && request.getDownloadedBytes() != 0) {
                outputStream.seek(request.getDownloadedBytes());
            }
            Log.d("miggy","siggy");
            if (request.getStatus() == Status.CANCELLED) {
                response.setCancelled(true);
                Data output = new Data.Builder()
                        .putString("Response",response+"")
                        .build();
                return Result.failure(output);
            } else if (request.getStatus() == Status.PAUSED) {
                response.setPaused(true);
                Data output = new Data.Builder()
                        .putString("Response",response+"")
                        .build();
                return Result.failure(output);
            }

            do {

                Log.d("left","some");
                final int byteCount = inputStream.read(buff, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);

                if (byteCount == -1) {
                    break;
                }

                outputStream.write(buff, 0, byteCount);

                request.setDownloadedBytes(request.getDownloadedBytes() + byteCount);
                Log.d("now1","one1");

                sendProgress();
                Log.d("now2","one2");
                syncIfRequired(outputStream);
                Log.d("common","yessin");
                if (request.getStatus() == Status.CANCELLED) {
                    response.setCancelled(true);
                    Data output = new Data.Builder()
                            .putString("Response",response+"")
                            .build();
                    return Result.failure(output);
                } else if (request.getStatus() == Status.PAUSED) {
                    sync(outputStream);
                    response.setPaused(true);
                    Data output = new Data.Builder()
                            .putString("Response",response+"")
                            .build();
                    return Result.failure(output);
                }

            } while (true);

            final String path = Utils.getPath(request.getDirPath(), request.getFileName());

            Utils.renameFileName(tempPath, path);

            response.setSuccessful(true);
            Log.d("yup","dove");

            if (isResumeSupported) {
                removeNoMoreNeededModelFromDatabase();
            }

        } catch (IOException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            if (!isResumeSupported) {
                deleteTempFile();
            }
            Error error = new Error();
            error.setConnectionError(true);
            error.setConnectionException(e);
            response.setError(error);
            Data output = new Data.Builder()
                    .putString("Response","def")
                    .build();
            return Result.failure(output);
        } finally {
            closeAllSafely(outputStream);
        }

        Log.d("final","done");
        Data output = new Data.Builder()
                .putString("Response","succ")
                .build();
        return Result.success(output);
    }
    private void deleteTempFile() {
        File file = new File(tempPath);
        if (file.exists()) {
            //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
            file.delete();
        }
    }

    private boolean isSuccessful() {
        return responseCode >= HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK
                && responseCode < HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MULT_CHOICE;
    }

    private void setResumeSupportedOrNot() {
        isResumeSupported = (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_PARTIAL);
    }

    private boolean checkIfFreshStartRequiredAndStart(DownloadModel model) throws IOException,
            IllegalAccessException {
        if (responseCode == Constants.HTTP_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE || isETagChanged(model)) {
            if (model != null) {
                removeNoMoreNeededModelFromDatabase();
            }
            deleteTempFile();
            request.setDownloadedBytes(0);
            request.setTotalBytes(0);
            httpClient = ComponentHolder.getInstance().getHttpClient();
            httpClient.connect(request);
            httpClient = Utils.getRedirectedConnectionIfAny(httpClient, request);
            responseCode = httpClient.getResponseCode();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isETagChanged(DownloadModel model) {
        return !(eTag == null || model == null || model.getETag() == null)
                && !model.getETag().equals(eTag);
    }

    private DownloadModel getDownloadModelIfAlreadyPresentInDatabase() {
        return ComponentHolder.getInstance().getDbHelper().find(request.getDownloadId());
    }

    private void createAndInsertNewModel() {
        DownloadModel model = new DownloadModel();
        model.setId(request.getDownloadId());
        model.setUrl(request.getUrl());
        model.setETag(eTag);
        model.setDirPath(request.getDirPath());
        model.setFileName(request.getFileName());
        model.setDownloadedBytes(request.getDownloadedBytes());
        model.setTotalBytes(totalBytes);
        model.setLastModifiedAt(System.currentTimeMillis());
        ComponentHolder.getInstance().getDbHelper().insert(model);
    }

    private void removeNoMoreNeededModelFromDatabase() {
        ComponentHolder.getInstance().getDbHelper().remove(request.getDownloadId());
    }

    private void sendProgress() {
        if (request.getStatus() != Status.CANCELLED) {
            Log.d("ttyl","ggyl");
            if (progressHandler != null) {
                Log.d("mozz","illa");
                progressHandler
                        .obtainMessage(Constants.UPDATE,
                                new Progress(request.getDownloadedBytes(),
                                        totalBytes)).sendToTarget();
            }
            else{
                Log.d("maybe","into");
            }
        }
    }

    private void syncIfRequired(FileDownloadOutputStream outputStream) {
        final long currentBytes = request.getDownloadedBytes();
        final long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final long bytesDelta = currentBytes - lastSyncBytes;
        final long timeDelta = currentTime - lastSyncTime;
        if (bytesDelta > MIN_BYTES_FOR_SYNC && timeDelta > TIME_GAP_FOR_SYNC) {
            sync(outputStream);
            lastSyncBytes = currentBytes;
            lastSyncTime = currentTime;
        }
    }

    private void sync(FileDownloadOutputStream outputStream) {
        boolean success;
        try {
            outputStream.flushAndSync();
            success = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            success = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (success && isResumeSupported) {
            ComponentHolder.getInstance().getDbHelper()
                    .updateProgress(request.getDownloadId(),
                            request.getDownloadedBytes(),
                            System.currentTimeMillis());
        }

    }

    private void closeAllSafely(FileDownloadOutputStream outputStream) {
        if (httpClient != null) {
            try {
                httpClient.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (inputStream != null) {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            if (outputStream != null) {
                try {
                    sync(outputStream);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (outputStream != null)
                try {
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }

    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream stream) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        if (stream != null) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
            try {
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException ignored) {

            } finally {
                try {
                    if (bufferedReader != null) {
                        bufferedReader.close();
                    }
                } catch (NullPointerException | IOException ignored) {

                }
            }
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Let me know if you need any more details of the code

Comment: There is no `getworkinfobyliveId()` method in your code (nor are there any calls to said method).

Comment: If you go deep down the code you will see an public void add request function which has a work manager.getworkinfobyliveId() function .This add request function is at the end of the class just above the myworker class.WorkManager.getInstance().getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(workRequest.getId()).observe(this, new Observer<WorkInfo>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable WorkInfo workInfo) {} .This the exact the thing inside add request function .Kindle help me figure why is it not called.Thanks for the response

Comment: Have you tried placing breakpoints in the code to determine if all the lines execute as expected?

Comment: Yes whole of the code is working just this function is not getting called .When code runs it just ignore this function and moves to all the lines ahead of it.I think the issue is because of active observers as in workmanager does not consider as active observe and hence shows no live data of the worker class.